# Showing subgraph timestamp results in human-readable format

Tags: graphql, thegraph

My subgraph as a UNIX timestamp as seconds defined as the following

```
type TokenSwap @entity {
  id: ID!

  # UNIX timestamp of block in which the swap was created
  timestamp: BigInt!
}
```

When I am [experimenting in TheGraph playground](https://thegraph.com/hosted-service/subgraph/miohtama/hackatom-2022?query=Example%20query), is there a way for me to display this as UTC time, instead of raw seconds since the UNIX epoch? This would make the playground output more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single responsibility of Graphql is to fetch a defined query, it doesn't support formatting data so you won't be able to do that in the playground.

It is possible to define a custom scalar type for a Date to control how it is serialized, deserialized, and validated [source](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types)

Unfortunately, a date type is not included in the scalar types supported by The Graph [source](https://thegraph.com/docs/en/developing/creating-a-subgraph/#built-in-scalar-types)

One solution would be to add an additional field with the human readable timestamp for convenience.

```
// schema 
type TokenSwap @entity {
  id: ID!

  # ISO String of block in which the swap was created
  isoString: String!
}

// handler
tokenswap.isoString = new Date(1665360258621).toISOString()
```